# Windows Phone 8 Font Binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fonts

I'm really stumped on how to go about binding fonts to a textbox. I'd like for my user to be able to choose between 3-4 different fonts. I have something like this right now:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True"  FontSize="20"
                     FontFamily="{Binding FontSelection}" />
```

But I have no clue how the c# should look, and I had no luck googling for it. What is the best way to do this? Do I have to create an observable collection? I've tried adding fonts to the Application.Resources, but it wouldn't let me.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: More about binding you will [find at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case you have to have in your code: property (!) FontSelection returning FontFamily type, the DataContext must be set properly depending on what you want. You may also want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the change will also update the UI. To all of this you will find many examples at SO, blogs, MSDN and more.

Answer (score 1):

This FontSelection property has to be single item. You could first try simple valid string (like 'Arial'), it could work. Another approach is FontFamily type as poined out by Romasz.

Also there are Converters available, quite easy to implement. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-25-Advanced-Binding-with-Value-Converters With this you could save user font selection as simple number for example and convert it to appropriate type with Converter.